# Aerospike config to use DNS instead of private ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aerospike

I am trying to configure aerospike to work in AWS. The recommended settings are to use Hearbeat mode mesh. Now I'm trying to use DNS say *trial.example.com* instead of IP in 
*mesh-seed-address-port **192.168.1.100** 3002* in this config but am unable to do so. The problem is the cluster visibility is shown False in AMC. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I work at Aerospike). Specifying a DNS entry instead of an IP address in the mesh-seed-address-port is currently not supported. So you will have to use an IP address (or a list of IP addresses). This is something that we may support at some point in the future.

Comment: Thank you. Will be looking forward to it.